# django query select_related()

Tags: django, django-models

I got a question concerning `select_related()`. Assuming I do not specify the depth nor the attributes i.e `items = ModelA.objects.selected_related()`, does it work for reverse relationship i.e items[0].fk_set?

Also, if we pass `items` into context and use it inside the django templates, will accessing the foreign keys of `items` inside the template hit the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work for reverse relationship, there will be additional database hit. You can easily check it yourself with [debug_tolbar](https://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar).

There is no difference where to evaluate queryset: in view or in template.